# Strength of core-envelope coupling in stars

Tags: astronomy, stars, stellar-evolution

For a star with a given Zero-Age Main Sequence (ZAMS) mass, as a function of metallicity how strongly is the star's core coupled to its envelope?

I understand that the core-envelope boundary is only (semi-) well defined for Main Sequence stars that do have a core, and that *in principle* the final spin (angular velocity) of the core should depend on the spin of the star prior to losing its envelope in a mass transfer event. I've read, [here](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2000MNRAS.315..543H) for instance, that the core should be nearly completely uncoupled from the envelope, however in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07053) recent paper they assume that the coupling is sufficient enough to determine the natal spin of the stellar core (see figure 1).

Is there a (preferably) simple way to understand the strength of core-envelope coupling in terms of the ZAMS quantities of the star, without performing full stellar population synthesis?... and without introducing another uncertain parameter, such as a timescale?

Comment: Please try to link to the abstract page, rather than the PDF (consider mobile users!).

Comment: @KyleKanos would this be better on the astronomy SE?

Comment: I think it's on topic here, but the lack of answers here might indicate that the users who could answer it haven't seen it. Editing it would bring it back to the top of the list, giving it more views. If that doesn't do it, asking in astronomy site might work also.